# Можно ли поменять строку поиска в sublime 3?

Tags: sublime-text

Всем привет. Кто-нибудь знает можно ли изменить строку поиска в sublime 3? Мне удобнее работать со строкой такой как в VS code, маленькая и аккуратная вверху справа, а не как в sublime большая на весь низ окна. Есть ли такой вариант замены?
Заранее спасибо